# using R.drawable in titanium module for android

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I am trying to create a module (native service for android) so that my appcelerator application can launch the native service.  The service is running fine, and it creates a relativeLayout a system_overlay  I am able to set that relativeLayout's background color, but ultimately i want to set its backgroundImage.  I have a png that i want to use for that background named: bg_noti

I have tried to do so in my native service class (inside the module project) like so:

```
String bg_name ="android.R.drawble.bg_noti";
        try {
            notificationBar.setBackgroundResource(TiRHelper.getApplicationResource(bg_name));
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.v(":::::::::::", "EXCEPTION:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my understanding is that i need to place the png somewhere in the Titanium app project, but no matter where i put it it doesn't seem to make its way into the compiled app..

i always get the exception that the resource is NOT found.

i was following the example found here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/49671/android-r-references-in-appcelerator-module

but they say to place the image in $APP_DIR/platform/android/res directory which doesn't exist.. i tried just creating it... but still doesn't work..

can someone please inform me as to where i am actually suppose to place this image in the titanium app project so that the module can reference it..

Answer (score 0):

You use the `getApplicationResource` method but you want an Android resource. You should try to use the `getAndroidResource` method :

```
String bg_name = "drawble.bg_noti";
try {
    notificationBar.setBackgroundResource(TiRHelper.getAndroidResource(bg_name));
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
    …
}
```

You should also change `bg_name` (`android.R.drawable.bg_noti` to `drawble.bg_noti`).